# AngularJS: Render tags dynamically in a separate div from a input box multiple times

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tags, angularjs-ng-repeat

Okay i have a ng-repeat which displays multiple students data, now inside each ng-repeat i want to add a tag section, which will contain tags. So, basically their will be a input element which takes sag name and adds it to the tag section for that particular student.

// This is inside **ng-repeat**

```
<form>
<div id="tags">
</div>
<br>
<input id="tagvalue" ng-keypress="myFunct($event)" class="inputTag"
       ng-model="addtags" placeholder="Add a tag"> 
</form>
```

// Inside **Controller**

```
$scope.myFunct = function(keyEvent) {
 if (keyEvent.which === 13)
 {
   var value = document.getElementById('tagvalue')
   var target = document.getElementById('tags');
   var newElement = angular.element("<span class='badge'>"+value.value+"</span>");

   angular.element(target).append(newElement);
   this.addtags=""
  }
}
```

The input field is created for all the students but tag section is working only for the first

Comment: Add the html with ng-repeat also

Comment: i couldn't understand, i have this form inside ng-repeat.

Comment: https://github.com/Bsingh2697/angularProj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using ID `tags` for getting the reference before you create the `<span>` element - and this `id` is being repeated for each student, this is why tags would be added for the first student only;

You can take a different approach where you add these tags to the student object itself and then simply print the tags using a nested ng-repeat;

working **snippet** below:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('formCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.firstname = "John";
  $scope.studentsData = [{
    name: 'Mr. one',
    tags: []
  }, {
    name: 'Ms. two',
    tags: []
  }, {
    name: 'Mr. three',
    tags: []
  }, {
    name: 'Mr. four',
    tags: []
  }, {
    name: 'Ms. five',
    tags: []
  }, ];

  $scope.myFunct = function(keyEvent, indexNumber) {

    if (keyEvent.which === 13 && this.addtags.length > 0) {
      var value = document.getElementById('tagvalue');
      $scope.studentsData[indexNumber].tags.push(this.addtags);
      this.addtags = "";
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.badge {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 2px;
}

input {
  float: right;
}

.students {
  margin: 5px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="formCtrl">
  <form>

    <div class='students' ng-repeat='item in studentsData'>
      Student Name: <b>{{item.name}}</b>
      <ng-container id="tags" ng-repeat='tag in item.tags' class='badge'>
        <span> {{tag}} </span>
      </ng-container>
      <input id="tagvalue" ng-keypress="myFunct($event, $index)" class="inputTag" ng-model="addtags" placeholder="Add a tag">

    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Kindly mark the answer as accepted - this will give you some points and give this answer more weightage for future reference